# Customised bar plot in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data to produce a bar chart in ggplot2 (R)

```
Bin Plr groupname   data    ci 
3   1%  solution    1002.97 6.98322
10  1%  solution    1001.7  1.25921
30  1%  solution    1176.47 12.1888
3   1%  w/o solution    1206.76 6.97126
10  1%  w/o solution    1211.65 1.81174
30  1%  w/o solution    1395.84 15.8956
3   4%  solution    1003.25 6.98989
10  4%  solution    1002.14 0.870957
30  4%  solution    1217.76 45.8752
3   4%  w/o solution    1207.18 6.99091
10  4%  w/o solution    1210.35 1.97528
30  4%  w/o solution    1470.81 48.6673
```

So, I am looking for two levels of grouping. Could anyone suggest me how to have the following bar chart from ggplot in R.
http://oi42.tinypic.com/2s8rb7m.jpg

Comment: I have tried one level of grouping (using only group name) and that was pretty easy. Something like qplot(factor(Bin),data=my_data,geom="bar",fill=groupname,weight=data,position="dodge",main = "Gain from using the solution", xlab="Size",ylab="Time [ms]")+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-ci, ymax=data+ci),width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))

Comment: If you see the picture in the url, you will find a further grouping using Plr but that have the same group of Bins

Comment: I usually use qplot for a simple x and y graphs, and ggplot syntax for more complicated ones. I don't know if its the best practice but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=bin, y=data, fill=groupname)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
+facet_wrap(~ plr )
+labs(title = "Gains from using the solution", x= "size", y= "time[ms]" )
```

edit2: sry, needed to cast x as factor so it does not go on a linear scale. Also slimmed it down a bit using width to match ur sample graph. My new idea:

```
(ggplot(my_data, aes(x=factor(Bin), y=data, fill=groupname, width=.65)) 
+ geom_bar( stat="identity", position="dodge")
+facet_wrap(~Plr )
+labs(title = "Gains from using the solution", x= "size", y= "time[ms]" )
 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-ci, ymax=data+ci),position="dodge") 
 )
```

Comment: This is just making a space between 10 and 30, how do you mean?

Comment: I can not post the picture. Could you please try the following, you will find what is missing : ggplot(my_data, aes(x=Bin, y=data, fill=groupname)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+ facet_wrap(~ Plr )+labs(title = "Gain from using the solution")+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-ci, ymax=data+ci),position="dodge")

Comment: Thanks. You did save a lot of my time.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to change the width of the error bar in relation to the width of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Using the help from Green Demon, I found the right way to make the chart I needed

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=factor(Bin), y=data, fill=groupname, width=.65)) + 
      geom_bar( stat="identity", position="dodge")+facet_wrap(~Plr ) +
      labs(title = "Gains from using the solution", x= "size", y= "time[ms]",
                                    linetype='custom title',fill="") + 
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=data-ci, ymax=data+ci),
                                    width=0.25,position=position_dodge(0.65))
```

[image]